How can I use Android Package Manager to extract apk meta data in Spring boot project?
I am developing spring boot gradle project with Java.
I made an POST api of uploading APK file to S3 Bucket.
I want to extract meta data of APK file after uploading the file with using Android Package Manager which can extract the ApplicationInfo.
But I am having a trouble with importing the android package from my spring boot gradle project.
I tried to import Android Package manager but I failed it.

Package Manager is an Android API not a generic Java api that can be used everywhere

In a Spring Boot project, importing and using Android-specific libraries like the Android Package Manager (which is part of the Android framework) is not feasible. But you will be able to solve this using APKParser. Please see this library https://github.com/hsiafan/apk-parser

Then is there any way to directly import Android library to Spring Boot project?

Because the execution method and structure of the project itself are different, you probably won't be able to do it directly.
